# Is `(T *)0 - (T *)0` well-defined to be 0?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, language-lawyer

Consider following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int *a = 0, *b = 0;
    std::cout << (a - b);
}
```

At [ideone](http://ideone.com/7addql) this code prints 0 as expected, but I'm not sure if it is well-defined behavior or not.

I wonder if `(T*)0 - (T*)0` is well-defined or not? Is it guaranteed to be equal to `0`?
Is it same in C and C++? If not, what are the differences?

(Of course, `T` is not `void` nor `std::nullptr_t`, because pointer arithmetic does not work for them.)

Comment: The older question is explicitly limited to old versions of C and C++.  This question was attracting answers for more modern versions, so I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy  Not sure I follow.  While it was tagged with older versions in addition to the generic c++ / c tags, the top voted answer cites what looks like the same source as the only answer to this question for the C++03 and C++11 versions of the standard

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++, see [[expr.add]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add):

> If two pointers […] both are null, and the two pointers are
>   subtracted, the result compares equal to the value `0` converted to
>   the type `std::ptrdiff_t`.

(This also holds with [P0137](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:mkV-de35tToJ:www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0137r0.html%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=de), which shortens this paragraph.)

In C11, the behavior is apparently undefined as per 6.5.6/9:

> When two pointers are subtracted, **both shall point to elements of the
>   same array object, or one past the last element of the array object**;
>   the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array
>   elements.

Comment: Linked to a google cache site, because open-std.org seems to (again) have server issues.